# data structure for insert, delete, contain and cover intervals for two different scenarios

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, intervals

Recently, I meet two different use cases related to interval:

define interval `[start, end)` as:

```
class Inteval {
    int start, end;
}
```

**First one**, I need to design a data structrue which has following APIs:

```
void insert(Interval interval);
boolean contain(Interval interval);
void remove(Interval interval);
```

For example:

I insert `[1,4)`, `[3, 6)`, `[9, 12)`, the internal interval is `[1, 6)`, `[9, 12)`.

If I call `contain([2, 5))`, it will return **true**, **although there is no seperate interval which can cover `[2, 5)`.**

`contain([4, 7)) return false`

When I `remove([10, 11))`, the internal interval is `[1, 6)`, `[9, 10)`, `[11, 12)`.

**My Question: What is best data structure for above use case? (assume all APIs have the same call frequency)**

**Second one**,  I need to design a data structrue which has following APIs:

```
void insert(Interval interval);
boolean has(Interval interval);
boolean cover(Interval interval);
boolean remove(Interval interval);
```

For example:

I insert `[1,4)`, `[1, 4)`, `[3, 6)`, `[9, 12)`, the internal interval is `[1,4)`, `[1, 4)`, `[3, 6)`, `[9, 12)`, not `[1, 6)`, `[9, 12)`(**Interval will not merge with each other**).

`boolean has(Interval interval)` means internal intervals **have an exactly same one**. `has([1,4)), return  true`, `has([1,2)), return false`.

`boolean cover(Interval interval)` means **there is at least one internal interval can fully cover, not the merge one**.

`boolean cover([2, 5)) return false`, although merging `[1, 4)` and `[3, 6)` can cover `[2, 5)` but neither of them can seperately cover.

`boolean cover([2, 3)) return true`, `cover([3, 4)) return true`.

`remove(Interval interval)` can only remove exactly same interval.

`remove([1, 3)) return false` `remove([1, 5)) return false` `remove([1, 4)) return true`, then internal interval will be `[1, 4)`,`[3, 6)`, `[9, 12)`.

**My Question: What is best data structure for second use case? (assume all APIs have the same call frequency)**

Comment: "best data structure for second use case" .. where is the 1st use case?

Comment: @p._phidot_ My question has first one use case and second use case. They are two different use cases which I met recently.

Comment: s - start interval, e - end interval `[ [s1,e1] , [s2,e2] , [s3,e3] ]` should do right?

Comment: @p._phidot_ Do you mean use sorted ArrayList? I will be slow for insert and remove

Comment: Performance benchmark can be only assessed if you have multiple data structure & multiple algo in mind.. what is your Option B data structure in mind.. ? (I'm assuming the accessing (API) algo is decided/fixed.) | Do I mean "sorted ArrayList", nope.

Comment: `has` is not a particularly interesting operation theoretically (use a separate set data structure). As for `insert/cover/remove`, I think the best data structure is likely to come out of recognizing interval containment as an instance of the 2D [maxima problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_of_a_point_set), which in turn is closely related to 2D convex hull, such that the fully dynamic algorithms for 2D convex hull can be repurposed. The textbook by de Berg et al. (including Overmars, who coauthored a seminal paper on dynamic hull with van Leeuwen) will have most of the details.